# Excel VBA password protect a command button

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a very large and somewhat fragile spreadsheet that I'm working on, and I'd like to limit access to more complicated macros--ones that delete or add data. I'm less worried about security than I am about someone who doesn't know what they're doing deleting unfortunate things. I've used the 'inputbox' password trick, but it becomes slightly annoying to have to keep putting in the password over and over. Is there any way to have the macro 'remember' that I put in the password once, and then reset after I close the sheet, without storing it in a cell somewhere?

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
Sub ControlPanel()

Dim PassProtect As Variant

PassProtect = InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter the password to unlock the updater." & vbCrLf & "(Case Sensitive)", Title:="Control Panel")

  If PassProtect = vbNullString Then Exit Sub

If PassProtect = "password" Then
    ControlPanelForm.Show vbModeless    
Else: MsgBox Prompt:="Incorrect password. Please try again.", Buttons:=vbOKOnly
End If

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why not check what the current username is? Are you in an Active Directory domain environment?

Answer (score 1):

Use a static string var within the CommandButton1_Click sub procedure. Once entered correctly, it will be 'remembered' for the duration of the session.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Static pwd As String

try_again:
    If pwd <> "thePassword" Then
        'password challenge
        pwd = InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter the password to unlock the updater." & vbLf & "(Case Sensitive)", _
                       Title:="Control Panel")

        'check if the password challenge was cancelled
        If pwd = vbNullString Then Exit Sub

        'compare again
        GoTo try_again
    End If

    'all the good code once the password challenge has been passed
    Debug.Print "pass"

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, I had not heard of a static variable before.  I tested it, and both a static variable in the sub or a public variable outside of the sub will work.  The static is probably a better approach because it is a more limited scope of the variable.

Comment: And since it is restricted to the sub procedure where it was declared, it is not openly available to other subs like a global public var (unless that was desirable).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a public variable to store a value when the workbook is open, so the code would become:

```
Public pblnEnteredPassword As Boolean

Sub ControlPanel()

    Dim PassProtect As Variant

    If pblnEnteredPassword Then GoTo DoStuff

    PassProtect = InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter the password to unlock the updater." & vbCrLf & "(Case Sensitive)", Title:="Control Panel")

      If PassProtect = vbNullString Then Exit Sub

    If PassProtect = "password" Then
        pblnEnteredPassword = True
        GoTo DoStuff
    Else
        MsgBox Prompt:="Incorrect password. Please try again.", Buttons:=vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

DoStuff:
    ControlPanelForm.Show vbModeless

End Sub
```

Comment: So, Alt+F11, then Ctrl+G, then `pblnEnteredPassword = True`, and poof, bypassed. A `Static` local would be better, however even that requires a hard-coded password, which is completely not secure at all and might as well not be there. By the way, that `pbln` prefix is called *Systems Hungarian*, and [it was a huge, stupid comprehension mistake](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/) that completely defeats the entire intended purpose of *Apps Hungarian*. Consider dropping these clumsy useless prefixes.

Comment: Could always use a txt file in the local directory - created when password entered (with the password in it for additional security) and deleted when you no longer need that password access. This not a full blown security measure, but a "readable token" so that it knows a password has been entered.